# Can't use Cplex as solver when using Pyomo

Tags: cplex, pyomo

Before I use Glpk to solve the abstract model but since Glpk might be slower than Cplex I turn to Cplex. But After I installed the Cplex and used it as a solver, I found that the Cplex can't open the logfile Pyomo create:

```
CPLEX> CPLEX Error  1422: Could not open file 'C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6u0194_4.cplex.log' for writing.
Could not open logfile -- please try another name.
Name of new logfile ('*' to close present file): Logfile 'read' open.
CPLEX> No problem exists.
CPLEX> No problem exists.
CPLEX> No problem exists.
CPLEX> Complete!
```

The above is what I got from tee=true

The Path contains Chinese letter so I'm not sure if it matters. If so, can I change the default path of the logfile Pyomo create?

Thanks,

Xuan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Pyomo is writing the `*.lp` CPLEX input file in a location with non-alphanumeric characters in the path name. The CPLEX invocation fails because of the path name, producing the reported error messages.

To correct the issue, a different temporary directory must be set. One way to do so is to do the following before the `SolverFactory('cplex').solve(model)` call:

```
import pyutilib.services
pyutilib.services.TempfileManager.tempdir = 'C:\user_writable_path'
```

This is similar to the issue addressed in https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/485.

Comment: It seems that the tmp_dir_path is read_only since it turns out PermissionError: [WinError 5]

Comment: Is there any possibility to change the default path of the tmp file of Pyomo?

Comment: Yeah. Try choosing a different path instead of tmp_dir_path. Somewhere that you have write permission, but no usual path names.

Comment: I've tried actually I can print out the logfile but still got the same problem above.

Comment: What are the contents of the logfile?

Comment: CPLEX> Logfile 'cplex.log' closed.

Logfile 'C:\Users\Public\Cplex\a.log' open.

CPLEX> File 'C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6b4mfwmq.pyomo.lp' not found.

No file read.

CPLEX> No problem exists.

CPLEX> No problem exists.

CPLEX> No problem exists.

CPLEX>

Comment: I've changed to the dir to \CPlex  but cplex still try to open the origin lp address

Comment: Maybe try this. Before calling `solve()`, set the temporary directory using the following: `import pyutilib.services` and `pyutilib.services.TempfileManager.tempdir = 'C:\CPlex'`

Comment: Ok, this solution works. Thanks! Can you tell the way it works?

Comment: @ironcircle I edited the answer to provide more explanation.